# If this conversion can never be correct, why was it adopted by Microsoft?

Tags: utf-8, visual-studio-2015, byte-order-mark

The figure below corresponds to Table 1 in [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/22/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/) by Jim Springfield from MS. I highlighted below the number 1252 in this table. I realize that the decision to assume that codepage 1252 was the source character set used to create the file was given in the article's previous page, with the following text (emphasis mine):

> If there is no BOM and it doesn’t look like UTF-16, then **we use the
>   current code page** (result of a call to GetACP) to convert the bytes on
>   disk into UTF-8. This may or may not be correct depending on how the
>   file was actually encoded and what characters it contains. **If the file
>   is actually encoded as UTF-8, this will never be correct** as the system
>   code page can’t be set to CP_UTF8.

If this conversion can never be correct (at least for the UTF-8 case), why was it adopted by MS? What's the rational behind this?

Basically, why can't they use the `UTF8 -> UTF8` conversion in this case?

I could confirm the facts shown above with this snippet, in which the file was saved with this special option: `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) codepage 65001`.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char c[] = u8"屰";
    int i = 1;
}
```

Also looking at the file contents with the binary editor I can see the bytes making up the character `屰`, 0xE5 0xB1 0xE0, which is the correct UTF-8 encoding for the Chinese character. Also looking at the memory occupied by the array `c[]`, I find the bytes 0xC3 0xA5 0xC2 0xB1 0xC2 0xB0 0x00, which corresponds exactly to the last line of Table 1 for the alluded column.

[image]

Comment: Because it makes perfect sense.  Without the BOM, you can never know if the file is UTF8 or not. It may contain Latin characters all the way up to the last line, then have a few UTF8-encoded characters. You can't know that without first loading everything though. You can only guess and using the current system locale is as good a guess as any.

Comment: BTW if you knew it's UTF8 you wouldn't need to convert anything. Just add a BOM to your files, or add a BOM to BOM-less files that you know are UTF8. Or treat the data as UTF8 in your code.

Comment: Then why do they have the option to save the file with `UTF-8 w/o BOM` as I did in my snippet above?

Comment: PS: The current codepage is actually the system's locale. In the regional settings, Administrative tab,  this is described as "Language for non-Unicode programs"

Comment: They explain it in the `Do's/Don'ts`. Some tools choke on BOM. That's the workaround, not the default.

Comment: `Without the BOM, you can never know if the file is UTF8 or not.` But VS2015 knows the file was saved with `UTF-8 w/o BOM`. Where does it keep this information?